# Dissolve on attribute field and location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, dissolve, proximity, parcel

I've got a county parcel shapefile and I'm wanting to find all the properties over 300 acres. When I dissolve based on ownership and search for dissolved properties that sum over 300 acres, some of the "properties" are not actually connected. For example, someone may own 100 acres on one side of the county and 200 acres on the other side of the county. This dissolves to one shape that is 300 acres, but it is obviously not a single 300 acre property. Is it possible to dissolve based on an attribute field AND only parcels that are near each other?

I'm working in ArcMap 10.5 with an Adv license.

Comment: In a two-step process, first dissolve, then use the `Explode` tool to split the multi-part polygons into single-part polygons.

Comment: Uncheck "create multipart" in dissolve dialogue.